# y∈ℝ, y>−1 and y≠0. Show that for k∈ℕ, k>1: (1+y)^k > 1+ky

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> > Let $y∈ℝ$, $y>−1$ and $y≠0$. Show that for $k∈ℕ$, $k>1$ we have $(1+y)^k > 1+ky$.

I've been trying to solve this for the last two hours and still don't really have any idea on how to do it.

Comment: Try induction with respect to $k$!

Comment: So what would I do with y then?

Comment: If $k=1$ your inequality is false (since both side are just $1+y$).

Comment: Cf. [Bernoulli's_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will prove that $$(1+y)^k\geq 1+ky$$.
For $k=1$ it is true.
Now we assume that $$(1+y)^k\geq 1+ky$$
Now we will prove that $$(1+y)^{k+1}\geq 1+(k+1)y$$
Multiplying $$(1+y)^k\geq 1+ky$$ by $y+1>0$ and we get
$$(1+y)^{k+1}\geq (1+ky)(1+y)=1+ky+y+ky^2$$ and now is is easy, that $$1+ky+y+ky\geq 1+(k+1)y$$ since $$ky^2\geq 0$$
It is Bernoulli's inequality